# How can I handle a sensitive settings file during deployment?

Tags: github, django

I am deploying a Django application to AWS using the following steps:

Push updates to GIT
Log into my server.
Pull updates from GIT

The issue I am having is my settings production.py file. I have it in my .gitignore so it does not get uploaded to GITHUB due to security. This, of course, means it is not available when I PULL updates onto my server.

What is a good approach for making this file available to my app when it is on the server without having to upload it to GITHUB where it is exposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into using environment variables for settings you wish to keep secret (like the SECRET_KEY). Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#on-the-server-mod-wsgi) to see how to use it for settings files. You can apply the same thing to your SECRET_KEY etc.

Also have a look at these two similar Stack Overflow questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693485/where-do-i-set-environment-variables-for-django
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variable-values

Comment: Thanks. I've since learned this is the correct way to do it.